# Generic type used only for other generic types

Tags: generics, rust

I'm currently trying to do the following:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait1 {}
pub trait MyTrait2<A: MyTrait1> {}
impl<A: MyTrait1, B: MyTrait2<A>> Add for B {
  ...
}
```

However, I then get the following error on the `A` type parameter in the impl:

> the type parameter `A` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
> unconstrained type parameter (rustc E0207)

Wondering if there's a way to get around this? I need the `A` type parameter to fill in as an argument to the `MyTrait2<_>` type.

Thanks!

Comment: What if whatever type `B` is implements both `MyTrait2<i32>` and `MyTrait2<bool>`? How should the compiler deduce which `A` (`i32` or `bool`) to use in your `Add` implementation?

Comment: @kmdreko that's a good question. I see the issue with allowing what I wrote above now, but still wondering if there's a common way to refactor the above idea i'm going for?

Comment: If you want to ensure that a type can only implement `MyTrait2` *once*, you can use an associated type instead of a generic parameter, [see here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2499ab858df3edbf4d13a6f613c4e92b). However, that code still has problems because you are implementing `Add` (I assume its the standard operator trait) on a generic type, which is not allowed due to Rust's trait coherence and orphan rules.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait1 {}
pub trait MyTrait2 {
    type Data: MyTrait1;
}

struct Wrapper<T>(T);
impl<A: MyTrait1, B> std::ops::Add<Wrapper<B>> for Wrapper<B>
where
    B: MyTrait2<Data = A>,
{
    type Output = Wrapper<B>;
    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```